# Integrating Selenium and Omnibug in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web, analytics

In my job, we are working on tracking events and eVars on our official website whenever a form is filled out. Our task involves visiting each page that contains a form and ensuring that the trackers for form filling are functioning correctly. To achieve this, I have developed a Python code using Selenium to automate the process of filling out a form.

Now, I want to integrate this automation with Omnibug so that after running the code, I can obtain a comprehensive list of all the fired events and eVars. How can I establish this connection between my code and Omnibug to retrieve the desired information?

The code below is the Selenium automation written so far:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

class Form():

#Creating service object, creating chrome service object and sending as property to the chrome service.
service = Service(r"C:\Users\ishag\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win32")
# Creating ChromeDriver instance with the service object
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)

def __init__(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)

def fillForm(self):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='First name*']").send_keys("Testing")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Last name*']").send_keys("Again")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Title*']").send_keys("Trial")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Company*']").send_keys("Insight")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Work phone*']").send_keys("612 456 7721")
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Business email*']").send_keys("againtesting9@gmail.com")
    # drop_down_menu =  self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='state']")
    #jk = Select(drop_down_menu)
    #jk.select_by_value("AZ")


url = "https://www.insight.com/en_US/content-and-resources/webinars/cyber-risk--financial-impacts-and-security-operations-value.html"
obj = Form(url)
obj.fillForm()
```